# Why doesn't clearInterval clear my interval?

Tags: javascript

So I'm using a Javascript interval and for some reason, clearing the interval does not work. This bug only happens when I'm on the page that has the timer, I press the back button (to go back on the previous page) and then I come on this one again.

Here is my timer :

```
var timeleft = 6;
var gameTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--; 
    afficherChaine("Le jeu va commencer dans " + timeleft + " secondes !"); //Just prints something at the screen for the user
    console.log("First");
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(gameTimer);
        console.log("Second");
        jouer();
    }
},1000);
```

When I return to the previous page using the back button, and then come back here, both timers will run and the timer will never stop, but `jouer()` will execute. But the timer doesn't stop.

Here's my log when I don't trigger the bug :

```
First
Second
```

And then after I trigger it :

```
First
Second
First
Second
First
Second
First
Second
...
```

And it never stops

EDIT : Apparently this is off-topic, and I don't really understand why. I think I need to say what the code is supposed to do.

The code works, but returning to the previous page and going on this one again creates a bug with 2 timers, even if I cleared the timer before. It's not supposed to do that.

EDIT (again) : First, thanks for your help. Then, here is a piece of code that create the bug :

```
var timeleft = 6;
var gameTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--; 
    afficherChaine("Le jeu va commencer dans " + timeleft + " secondes !"); //Just prints something at the screen for the user
    console.log("First");
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(gameTimer);
        console.log("Second");
    }
},1000);
```

I've tried not to call the method jouer(), but the bug still occurs. Also, the bug only appears when you press the back button (or whatever its name is) and come on this page again

And afficherChaine :

```
function afficherChaine(message){ 
    affichageChaine.textContent = message;
}
```

Comment: what `afficherChaine` does?

Comment: How/when does that code run? Is it inside some other function? Is it in an event handler?

Comment: Guess: you're either restarting the interval elsewhere, or you overwrite `gameTimer` with some other value.

Comment: This does stop. So, I'm not sure what the issue you have is.

Comment: What's `jouer()`? Is that potentially causing the `setInterval` to be run again? Does that function wrap all this code?

Comment: [JSBin of me not reproducing the issue](https://jsbin.com/fulemig/edit?js,console)

Comment: @TheReason : `function afficherChaine(message){ affichageChaine.textContent = message; }`

Comment: I'm not using gameTimer anywhere else. And @Pointy, this code runs when the page shows

Comment: @Carcigenicate jouer() is a big method, but I'm not using the interval in it

Comment: @PapyPoule Does that function end up at some point calling the code here?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Nope. jouer() doesn't use anything that comes from outside

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah as I said, the bug only happens when I return to the previous page and come back on this one after. Just coming on this page doesn't create any bug, like in your example

Comment: This question is off-topic because we can't say why it doesn't work. You haven given us a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. For all we know, you might be running the code multiple times manually or have a typo somewhere. Whatever fix we suggest would be pure guesswork.

Comment: As for why this is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help [..] must include [..] __code necessary to reproduce [the problem]__*. – We can't reproduce the problem given this code.

Comment: And I can't say why it doesn't work because I DON'T KNOW why it doesn't work. I wouldn't be asking for help if I knew how to fix the bug.

Comment: You don't need to tell us why it doesn't work, you need to give us enough code that we could run to see this problem in action ourselves.

Comment: Well timers stop running when you go back a page, *unless* your "go back" is something other than the normal "Back" button.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using the normal back button

Comment: Is this a single page application? If so, which library do you use for it? A lot will hijack the back-forward in order to force the user to stay in the same page.

Comment: @VLAZ Not a single page. I only have a text on the previous page and a button. The button only redirects to this page. And I'm using ruby on rails, I didn't add any other gem. Rails 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.4.4

Comment: @deceze I gave all the code that creates the bug

Comment: @PapyPoule Depending on the browser you're using the page is "reloaded" or "restored". Firefox for example doesn't send out a new request, but loads the previous page from cache. Google Chrome does send out new requests when pressing the *back* button. Does your issue occur within multiple different browsers?